# Magento 1.9 : Swatch Image is not appearing at frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, swatches, color-swatches

My swatch option name is

`Black - 100% Italian Leather (Italian Leather)`

and my image name is

`black_-_100%_Italian_Leather_(Italian_Leather).png`

I had also try with this name but not work

`black---100%-italian-leather-(italian-leather).png`

Swatch image is located at `media/wysiwyg/swatches` folder

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The images should be a .png file with the word -swatch afterwards — for example, Black-swatch.png or Blue-swatch.png

Answer (score 0):

The correct name would be

```
black---100--italian-leather--italian-leather-.png
```

#### Rules:

- transliterate to ASCII
- change characters to lower case
- replace every character that is not a letter or a digit with a dash "-"

See here fore details of the implementation and some special cases where this is not working:

[Magento CE 1.9.1.0 greek characters in configurable swatches](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54648/magento-ce-1-9-1-0-greek-characters-in-configurable-swatches/78259#78259)

Comment: this one not working for me.